Error while dockerizing spring-boot and mysql. Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
I am trying to dockerize my Spring Boot app with MySql.
While doing it I am getting error:
> org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect
> does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect'
> (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default) db-1 
> | 2024-09-19T10:35:56.442175Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A
> deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main db-1  
> | 2024-09-19T10:35:56.442209Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A
> deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main db-1 
> | 2024-09-19T10:35:56.730732Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server]
> root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider
> switching off the --initialize-insecure option. app-1  |
> 2024-09-19T10:35:57.344Z  INFO 1 --- [dockerFile] [           main]
> o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform
> available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA
> platform integration) app-1  | 2024-09-19T10:35:57.382Z  INFO 1 ---
> [dockerFile] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource     
> : HikariPool-1 - Starting... app-1  | 2024-09-19T10:35:58.513Z  WARN 1
> --- [dockerFile] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
> 08S01 app-1  | 2024-09-19T10:35:58.514Z ERROR 1 --- [dockerFile] [    
> main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   :
> 
> 
> ***Communications link failure app-1  |  app-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
> received any packets from the server. app-1  |
> 2024-09-19T10:35:58.523Z ERROR 1 --- [dockerFile] [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA
> EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build
> Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC
> Connection for DDL execution [Communications link failure app-1  | 
> app-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0
> milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the
> server.] [n/a] app-1  | 2024-09-19T10:35:58.524Z  WARN 1 ---
> [dockerFile] [           main]*** 
> 
> 
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
> Unable to open JDBC Connection

It is working fine on the localhost but while dockerizing it I am getting error.
Here is my application.properties:
spring.application.name=dockerFile
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localspringbootdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=use1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /opt
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar

docker-compose.yml
version: '2.29.4'

services:
  app:
    image: javademo
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/localspringbootdb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root


    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localspringbootdb
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

Here is the complete source code and files for your reference:
https://github.com/KapilKokcha/Dockerized-Spring-Boot-And-Mysql
I have tried to create the docker from all these but getting failed and not sure why.

Please add the full error and while doing see please use code tags for formatting, currently it is unreadable. You are exposing port 3307 not 3306.

the error is quite clear, it says straight up that it cant connect to the database. So that is your problem. We know nothing about your database setup and nothing about how you run these things. So this is impossible to answer. Voted to close and this just looks fishy 3307:3306 and your dockerfile is not exposing the database port

Why I need to expose port for DB in dockerfile? I am exposing port 3306 on port 3307. Also what should I tell about my db setup ? @Toerktumlare

I have formatted the the error. And Yes I am exposing the port 3306 on port 3307.

unless you are running you database inside the docker container, you need to expose the port to the outside world so it can reach the edatabase outside your docker container.

The issue was when tomcat was trying to connect to the mysql server but it was not completely loaded and hence causing connection error.
To solve this I added a health check for mysql server and now tomcat depends on healthy database container.
Here is the updated docker-compose.yml
version: '2.29.4'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localspringbootdb
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5

  app:
    image: javademo
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/localspringbootdb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

I have also updated the repo : https://github.com/KapilKokcha/Dockerized-Spring-Boot-And-Mysql
Feel free to suggest any change or recommend the good practice.
